# Multiple key search in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Given the following object structure:

```
{
   key1: "...",
   key2: "...",
   data: "..."
}
```

Is there any way to get this object from a CouchDB by quering both key1 and key2 without setting up two different views (one for each key) like:

```
select * from ... where key1=123 or key2=123
```

Kind regards,
Artjom

**edit:**

Here is a better description of the problem:
The object described above is a serialized game state. A game has exactly one creator user (key1) and his opponent (key2). For a given user I would like to get all games where he is involved (both as creator and opponent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emit both keys (or only one if equal):

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.hasOwnProperty('key1')) {
    emit(doc.key1, 1);
  }
  if (doc.hasOwnProperty('key2') && doc.key1 !== doc.key2) {
    emit(doc.key2, 1);
  }
}
```

Query with (*properly url-encoded*):

```
?include_docs=true&key=123
```

or with multiple values:

```
?include_docs=true&keys=[123,567,...]
```

**UPDATE:** updated to query multiple values with a single query.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a CouchDB view which produces output such as:

```
["key1", 111],
["key1", 123],
["key2", 111],
["key2", 123],
etc.
```

It is very simple to write a map view in javascript:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(["key1", doc["key1"]], null);
    emit(["key2", doc["key2"]], null);
}
```

When querying, you can query using multiple keys:

```
{"keys": [["key1", 123], ["key2", 123]]}
```

You can send that JSON as the data in a POST to the view. Or preferably use an API for your programming language. The results of this query will be each row in the view that matches either key. So, every document which matches on both key1 and key2 will return two rows in the view results.

Answer (score 1):

I also was struggling with simular question, how to use

```
"select * from ... where key1=123 or key2=123".
```

The following view would allow you to lookup customer documents by the LastName **or** FirstName fields:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.Type == "customer") {
      emit(doc.LastName, {FirstName: doc.FirstName, Address: doc.Address});
      emit(doc.FirstName, {LastName: doc.LastName, Address: doc.Address});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this for a web service that queries all my docs and returns every doc that matches both the existence of a node and the query. In this example I am using the node 'detail' for the search. If you would like to search a different node, you need to specify.

This is my first Stack Overflow post, so I hope I can help someone out :)

```
***Python Code

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import httplib, json

from tornado.options import define,options

define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        db_host = 'YOUR_COUCHDB_SERVER'
        db_port = 5984
        db_name = 'YOUR_COUCHDB_DATABASE'

        node = self.get_argument('node',None)
        query = self.get_argument('query',None)

        cleared = None
        cleared = 1 if node else self.write('You have not supplied an object node.<br>')
        cleared = 2 if query else self.write('You have not supplied a query string.<br>')

        if cleared is 2:
            uri = ''.join(['/', db_name, '/', '_design/keysearch/_view/' + node + '/?startkey="' + query + '"&endkey="' + query + '\u9999"'])
            connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(db_host, db_port)
            headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
            connection.request("GET", uri, None, headers)
            response = connection.getresponse()
            self.write(json.dumps(json.loads(response.read()), sort_keys=True, indent=4))

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler)
        ]
        settings = dict(
            debug = True
        )
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


***CouchDB Design View
{
   "_id": "_design/keysearch",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "detail": {
           "map": "function(doc) { var docs = doc['detail'].match(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/g); if(docs) { for(var each in docs) { emit(docs[each],doc); } } }"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. You can always edit your own post to add relevant information by clicking on the "edit" link button just below it. You should do that and remove your comment once the info is in your answer :) Good luck, Have a look to our Help section for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/3596626#